# Issue with laravel date / time

Tags: php, laravel-5

I ran into a small issue, I get the error `laravel`

Most everything says `strtotime()` will fix this, I have already used it but still error is there.

```
<?php if($s1->ongoing == false): ?>

<?php if((number_format((strtotime($s1->next_election) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"))) / 3600, 1)) - 24 <= 24): ?>
```

Error is:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: remove `a` from `"Y-m-d h:i:sa"` and check

Comment: You can replace `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` with just `time()`. It will give you the same result.

Comment: @HeyItsAlex did you checked the answers?

Answer (score 0):

use round(exp, 1) replace number_format(exp, 1)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

> '1,235' - 24;
>   PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered on line 1